# how to get page link of searched result in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i tried this code in the read more button i want the link of page

```
<div class="blogleft">
  <ul class="eachblog">
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <li>
      <h1>
        <?php the_title();?>
      </h1>
      <div class="perpostbg">
       <?php $content = get_the_content(); echo substr($content,0,400); echo '...';?>
        <a href="#" class="readmorebutton">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </li>
   <?php endwhile;?>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use permalink

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="readmorebutton">Read more</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmorebutton">Read more</a>
```

Comment: no Dear i want the link of page 

example: like if i search any word that is in faq post
then i want the link of faq page on read more button

Comment: try this, I feel it will return you the link of post/page.

Comment: no its not give the url of page and can u tell me how to open full comment on recent comments

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore">Read more</a>
```

This code in your search loop

Comment: no Dear i want the link of page example: like if i search any word that is in faq post then i want the link of faq page on read more button